# If I'm slowed/exhausted and then I ghost/speed up, how does the speed % stack?

Tags: league-of-legends

Does the effects matter in order such as exhaust over ghost? or does the slow percent prioritze over the speed increase, vice versa?

Comment: Very insightful answer Murr4y

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, **the order doesn't matter**, both the slow and boost will be applied. However, the slow will always be more effective, so it's not necessarily worth to pop ghost while exhausted.

From http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Movement_speed, movement speed is calculated by:

> Movement Speed = (Base Movement Speed + Flat Movement Bonuses) × (1 + Percentage Movement Bonuses) × Slow Ratio

E.g. if you have 310 base speed, your effective speed with both ghost (27% boost) and exhaust (40% slow) will be:

> 310 * 1.27 * 0.6 = 236.2

So the order doesn't matter, the end result is always the same. However, the slow is always more effective, because it's a ratio of the effective speed *with* boosts.

From the example above, normally ghosting would give you `83.7` extra speed, however, if you ghost *while exhausted*, you gain only `50.2`.

Likewise, being exhausted normally subtracts `124` speed, but being exhausted *while ghosting* would subtract `157.5`.

Another example; if you slow and boost yourself by an equal amount, say 20%, the net effect would be that you're slowed:

> 310 * 1.2 * 0.8 = 297.6

Comment: nice answer. but when I ghost while exhausted it does not look make any effect, until exhaustion is over. Are you sure about the speed up ?

Comment: Well -- as the math in this example shows, exhaust sets you down to `124`, and ghosting would only improve that to `157` -- when your normal speed is `310`, I guess you really won't feel that improvement at all.

Comment: Sorry, my numbers were off. You'd be set down to `186` and improve it to `236.2`, but the same argument still applies. It's a slight improvement, but still well below your normal speed.